# Обработка видеофайла; Revers; Поворот на 90 градусов; Сделать видео черно-белым;

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ffmpeg

Использую Linux Server.
Возможно ли, с помощью Python, OpenCV, C, ffmpeg или еще чем-то, выполнить данные действия с видео: Revers; Поворот на 90 градусов; Сделать видео черно-белым;Зеркально отобразить видео;
Если да, то какие есть варианты исполнения, какие библиотеки, мануалы, статьи и т.д. Ключевые слова поиска. В интернете пока ничего не удалось найти.

Comment: Вроде в ffmpeg должны быть все нужные фильтры

Answer (score 1):

Всё это делается элементарно с помощью gStreamer. Там огромное количество плагинов, в которых есть всё, что Вы перечислили и много чего другого.

[Популярное введение в gStreamer](https://habrahabr.ru/post/178813/)